# Como efetuar login em um Website através de uma aplicação webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms, login

Preciso fazer login automatico da minha aplicação webforms e outra aplicação, e gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de fazer isto. Algumas opções que pesquisei foi a classe HTTPWebRequest, Selenium Toolkit for .NET. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: E o que você fez? Qual é sua dúvida? Leia o [tour] e o [ask].

Comment: Olá, desculpe não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta. Você já tem uma aplicação Web e precisa utiliza-la para fazer login em outra ?

Answer (score 0):

Muito fácil. Siga esses passos:

1. Identifique o tipo de requisição esperada pelo site: GET/POST/Outra
2. Identifique os parâmetros esperados pela requisição
3. Use uma biblioteca para fazer as requisições. Você pode usar a classe HttpWebRequest também

Provavelmente o website retorna algo para que seja usado nas próximas requisições, assim é só passar essa informação nas próximas requisições.